# How to set cluster name in DataDog Helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, datadog

I'm using the DataDog Helm chart to install the DataDog agent on my EKS Kubernetes clusters (https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/datadog). The problem I'm having now is that I am not able to filter logs by cluster name. I have also set the `DD_CLUSTER_NAME` environment variable but it does not seem to do anything.

I have set the following in my values.yml file:

```
datadog:
  site: datadoghq.com
  logLevel: ERROR

  logsEnabled: true
  logsConfigContainerCollectAll: true
  processAgentEnabled: true
  apmEnabled: true
  nonLocalTraffic: true
  leaderElection: true
  collectEvents: true

  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 100Mi
    limits:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 500Mi

  nodeLabelsAsTags:
    beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type: aws_instance_type
    kubernetes.io/role: kube_role
  podAnnotationsAsTags:
    iam.amazonaws.com/role: kube_iamrole
  podLabelsAsTags:
    app: kube_app
    release: helm_release

clusterAgent:
  enabled: true
```

Answer (score 9):

I believe you are looking for `clusterName`:
https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/datadog/values.yaml#L75

You can add it in your `values.yaml` under the `datadog` section like this:

```
datadog:
  clusterName: myexamplename
```

Answer (score 4):

refer below command

```
helm install --name datadog-monitoring \
    --set datadog.apiKey=<DATADOG_API_KEY> \
    --set datadog.appKey=<DATADOG_APP_KEY \
    --set clusterAgent.enabled=true \
    --set clusterAgent.metricsProvider.enabled=true \
    --set datadog.clusterName=<CLUSTER_NAME> \
    stable/datadog
```